# How to push docker image created through save command to remote registry without docker client

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I looking for method to push tar file with image created by save command to remote docker repository using curl or something similar. So I looking for analog to

```
docker tag some/image repository:5000/some/image
docker push repository:5000/some/image
```

but without installed docker client. I came up with code like

```
userToken=$(oc login -u admin -p password > /dev/null && oc whoami -t)
uploadURL=$(curl -u admin:"$userToken" -si -X POST "172.30.118.161:5000/v2/some/image/blobs/uploads/" | grep 'Location:' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | tr -d '[:space:]')
digest="sha256:$(sha256sum image.tar | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
curl -v -u admin:"$userToken" -T image.tar "$uploadURL&digest=$digest"
curl -v -u admin:"$userToken" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -T manifest.json -X PUT "172.30.118.161:5000/v2/some/image/manifests/latest"
```

And it seems I successfully push image but cannot push manifest file. I do not know how to create it from scratch because of JWS and image structure(history and layers). I can create fsLayers from tar structure, but not JWS and history. May be there is more simple solution?

Comment: Can I ask why? Do you have a very specific use case that prevents you from using push?

Comment: @Marakai it is limitation of our environment. We assume that docker client is absent during push procedure. Also it is kind of personal interest now - how I can use REST API without official client.

Comment: That's quite a valid case. So much so that I'm now interested myself. I may have a try for some options myself today. That said, as you a) will use a remote connection anyway and b) have the Docker host with the registry container (presumably) anyway, couldn't you simply call Docker commands remotely and stream your image through an SSH pipe?
"cat <image> | ssh -C ... docker load ..."? Then also remotely have that docker host inject the image into the registry and clean up afterwards, if you so desire.

Comment: @Marakai docker registry under Openshift control and can be on any node (registry is docker container too) and I cannot be sure if right node (or any of them) will have open ssh port to connect. I can try similar approach with openshift rsync/exec functions.

Comment: I see. I hope somebody comes up with an answer, I'm now really curious myself as I can't see an easy one that isn't somewhat convoluted (or requires some custom code which itself would raise dependencies).

Answer (score -1):

Push built docker image to Docker registry

> docker push image-name

You might need to create/update the config file:
 /etc/docker/daemon.json with

> { "insecure-registries":["myregistry.example.com:5000"] }

and the need to restart the docker:

> sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart